# R reshape - Can't seem to cast data frame as I need it

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

I've been playing with `reshape` for a couple of hours now and I can't seem to cast my data frame into the form I need it in. Simply put, I have several id variables but also two value variables. Take the long form df below.

```
playerid    leagueid    franchise   week    score   variable    value
10048       10087       11          1       7       tran_type   nonstart
10074       10087       2           1       11      tran_type   start
10077       10087       7           1       17      tran_type   start
10260       10087       6           2       8       tran_type   nonstart
10267       10087       7           2       7       tran_type   start
10269       10087       12          2       23      tran_type   start
```

I'd like to reshape this data frame into the following, such that the new wide columns are named by the `week` value followed by the type of data contained within the cells (e.g., 'value' for .value columns and 'score' for .score columns).

```
playerid    leagueid    franchise   1.value     1.score     2.value     2.score
10048       10087       11          nonstart    7       
10074       10087       2           start       11  
10077       10087       7           start       17  
10260       10087       6                                   nonstart    8
10267       10087       7                                   start       7   
10269       10087       12                                  start       23
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the capabilities of `reshape` but would greatly appreciate guidance as to how to transform my data as desired- I have spent so much time on this already attempting different permutations of variables in the `cast` function. Thank you!

Comment: Could you also share some code?

Comment: `reshape(dat, direction="wide", idvar=c("playerid","leagueid","franchise"), timevar="week")`

Comment: @thelatemail Any reason that this isn't an answer?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - my laziness, probably a duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dta %>% mutate(week2 = paste0(week, ".value"),
               week = paste0(week, ".score")) %>%
        spread(week, score) %>%
        spread(week2, value)

  playerid leagueid franchise  variable 1.score 2.score  1.value  2.value
1    10048    10087        11 tran_type       7      NA nonstart     <NA>
2    10074    10087         2 tran_type      11      NA    start     <NA>
3    10077    10087         7 tran_type      17      NA    start     <NA>
4    10260    10087         6 tran_type      NA       8     <NA> nonstart
5    10267    10087         7 tran_type      NA       7     <NA>    start
6    10269    10087        12 tran_type      NA      23     <NA>    start
```

You could also use `unite`:

```
z <- dta %>% unite(temp, score, value) %>%
             spread(week, temp)

  playerid leagueid franchise  variable          1          2
1    10048    10087        11 tran_type 7_nonstart       <NA>
2    10074    10087         2 tran_type   11_start       <NA>
3    10077    10087         7 tran_type   17_start       <NA>
4    10260    10087         6 tran_type       <NA> 8_nonstart
5    10267    10087         7 tran_type       <NA>    7_start
6    10269    10087        12 tran_type       <NA>   23_start
```

If you want the values in seperate columns, use `separate`:

```
z %>% separate("1", c("1.score", "1.value"), extra="drop") %>%
      separate("2", c("2.score", "2.value"), extra="drop")

  playerid leagueid franchise  variable 1.score  1.value 2.score  2.value
1    10048    10087        11 tran_type       7 nonstart    <NA>     <NA>
2    10074    10087         2 tran_type      11    start    <NA>     <NA>
3    10077    10087         7 tran_type      17    start    <NA>     <NA>
4    10260    10087         6 tran_type    <NA>     <NA>       8 nonstart
5    10267    10087         7 tran_type    <NA>     <NA>       7    start
6    10269    10087        12 tran_type    <NA>     <NA>      23    start
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `dcast` from the `devel` version of `data.table` where we can pass multiple value columns in the `value.var`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`) and use `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(df1), playerid+leagueid+franchise ~ week,
                     value.var=c('score', 'value'), sep='.')
#     playerid leagueid franchise score.1 score.2  value.1  value.2
#1:    10048    10087        11       7      NA nonstart       NA
#2:    10074    10087         2      11      NA    start       NA
#3:    10077    10087         7      17      NA    start       NA
#4:    10260    10087         6      NA       8       NA nonstart
#5:    10267    10087         7      NA       7       NA    start
#6:    10269    10087        12      NA      23       NA    start
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version of data.table are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)